# sorting an array of folder names for displaying the content of a folder

Tags: php

I have wrote a function for getting all the subfolders of a folder. It also has the option of going the an upper level and displaying the folders....much like a file manager but it works only for folders and has a restriction to not go upper than the base folder so to prevent users from browsing the entire hard disk.

I am returning the result as a json object to be put in a div. My problem is this: 
On my windows box (using wamp) the folder "Up one Level" is always displayed on top of the folder list. When I upload it on my website it doesn't display on top but somewhere in the middle. I have wrote a function ( fixArray($array) ) to correct this...but it doesn't seem to work. The entire solution for this feature is provided so please help to make it work and for others to benefit from it.
Just to mention: there is nothing wrong in the JS code. JSON object is parsed in the order it is sent by the php file.

```
function fixPath($path) {
    $path = str_replace('/../', '/', $path);
    $path = str_replace('/./', '/', $path);
    return $path;
}
function fixArray($array) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if(!strcmp($array[$i]['name'],"Up one Level")) {
            $aux = $array[$i];
            $array[$i] = $array[0];
            $array[0] = $array[$i];
            break;
        }
    }
}

function directoryList($basepath, $path) {
        $dirStruct = array();
        if(is_dir($path)) {
            $handle = opendir($path);
            while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
                if($file != '.') {
                    if(@opendir($path.$file)) {
                        $newpath = "";
                        if($file == '..') {//begin constructing the path for the upper level
                            $array = @split('/',$path);

                            $up = "";
                            for($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 2; $i++) {
                                $up = $up.$array[$i].'/';
                            }
                            $file = "Up one Level";
                            //if the upper level exceeds the home dir
                            if(strcmp($up,$basepath) < 0) {
                                $newpath = $basepath;//use the basepath
                            }
                            else {
                                $newpath = $up;
                            }
                        }
                        else {//construct the path for a normal dir
                            $newpath = $path.$file.'/';
                            $newpath = fixPath($newpath);
                        }
                        $dirStruct[] = array('path' => $newpath, 'name'=>$file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //sortArray($dirStruct);
        fixpath($dirStruct);
        return $dirStruct;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass it by reference to keep the change :)

```
function fixArray(&$array) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if($array[$i]['name'] == "Up one Level") {
            $up = $array[$i];
            unset($array[$i]);
            array_unshift($array,$up);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your swap is swapping then swapping back. `$array[0] = $array[$i];` should be `$array[0] = $aux;`

But that will swap the original first element into the middle of the array. You can do it by just moving the target element to the front of the array.

Try this:

```
function fixArray($array) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if($array[$i]['name'] === "Up one Level") {
            $aux = $array[$i];
            array_unshift($array, $aux);
            unset($array[$i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

and call like:

```
$dirStruct = fixpath($dirStruct);
```

Comment: won't work, doesn't pass by reference or return the new array - essentially it just runs then all modifications are forgotten ;)